# Access Computed Property of a Protocol in a Protocol Extension

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

Assume I have a protocol like

```
protocol TypedString : CustomStringConvertible, Equatable, Hashable { }

func == <S : TypedString, T : TypedString> (lhs : T, rhs : S) -> Bool {
    return lhs.description == rhs.description
}
```

I want to be able to provide a default implementation of `Hashable`:

```
extension TypedString {
    var hashValue = { return self.description.hashValue }
}
```

But the problem is that I get an error `Use of unresolved identifier self`.

How do I create a default implementation of `Hashable` using the string representation given by the `description` property defined in the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol?

---

The motivation is I want to create shallow wrappers around Strings, so I can semantically type-check my code. For example instead of writing `func login (u : String, p : String) -> Bool` I would instead write `func login (u : UserName, p : Password) -> Bool` where the (failable) initialisers for `UserName` and `Password` do validation. For example I might write

```
struct UserName : TypedString {
    let description : String

    init?(userName : String) {
        if userName.isEmpty { return nil; }

        self.description = userName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is totally possible, the error message you're receiving just isn't making it very clear what the problem is: your syntax for a computed property is incorrect. Computed properties need to be explicitly typed and don't use an equals sign:

```
extension TypedString {
    var hashValue: Int { return self.description.hashValue }
}
```

This works fine!